# Loading indicator that displays when all async actions are complete and has minimum display time for better UX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a loading indicator that is displaying correctly when all async actions are complete. This is accomplished using a separate `isFetching` store that will flag an action as true or false depending on if it's still loading or not.

For example, the `isLoading` prop below would return an object containing all of the app's actions and their current loading state like:

```
isLoading: {
    SOME_ACTION_FIRST: false,
    SOME_ACTION_SECOND: true,
    SOME_ACTION_THIRD: false
}
```

With that, I can conditionally display the loader to display only if not all of the actions are in a `false` state. This works great and all is right with the world.

```
class ExampleComponentUsingLoader extends Component {

    checkForallFalseValues = (obj) => {
      return Object.keys(obj).every(function(val){ 
        return obj[val] === false 
      })
    }

    render(){
        const { isLoading } = this.props
        return(
            { !allFalseValues(loading) && <LoadingIndicator /> }
        )
    }
}
```

**Where things get tricky - Minimum Time Loading Indication**

The user experience in React is a blessing and a curse. On the one hand it's really fast and this can feel magical. On the other, it can be too fast and this is a really jarring experience.

From a post on the UX stack exchange, it's generally thought that 1 second is an ideal length for a user's flow:

> 1 second keeps the user's flow of thought seamless. Users can sense a
>   delay, and thus know the computer is generating the outcome, but they
>   still feel in control of the overall experience and that they're
>   moving freely rather than waiting on the computer. This degree of
>   responsiveness is needed for good navigation.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104606/should-a-loading-text-or-spinner-stay-a-minimum-time-on-screen#answer-104782

So my goal is not only to display the indicator based on the loading state of actions *but to also give it a minimum display time*.

Things I need to consider:

1. In some scenarios, the actions will take longer than 1 second in which case, I only want to display the indicator for that amount of time.
2. In other cases, the actions will take less than 1 second and in this case, I need to make sure the indicator displays for a minimum 1 second.

**What I've tried**

I've experimented with `setTimeout` which works if I just want to add a general delay but this isn't really my goal:

```
class LoadingIndicator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.enableMessage = this.enableMessage.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      displayMessage: false,
    };

    this.timer = setTimeout(this.enableMessage, 250);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  enableMessage() {
    this.setState({displayMessage: true});
  }

  render() {
    const {displayMessage} = this.state;

    if (!displayMessage) {
      return null;
    }

    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}
```

I'm looking for some suggestions for the best way to incorporate that type of idea with the actual loading time from the `isLoading` actions reducer prop.

Answer (score 0):

I started coming up with a solution that is fairly complex and then realized there is a much simpler one. Both use promises. I don't have much experience with React or Promises, but I think something similar to this should get you close. I'll give the simple one first:

```
class ExampleComponentUsingLoader extends Component {

  checkForallFalseValues = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(val){ 
      return obj[val] === false 
    })
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.delayedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000))

    this.state = { loading: true, delayMet: false }
    this.delayedPromise.then(() => this.setState({ delayMet: true }))
  }

  render(){
    const { isLoading } = this.props
    if (checkForAllFalseValues(isLoading)) {
      this.state.setState({ loading: false });
    }
    return(
        { !(this.state.delayMet && !this.state.loading) && <LoadingIndicator /> }
    )
  }
}
```

This is the more complex example. I don't have much experience with Javascript classes either so I used a function for the `DelayedPromise` class so I could make sure my scoping works:

```js
function DelayedPromise(delay) {
  const self = this;
  
  // This is what takes care of the timing, it will resolve after the delay
  const timerPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, delay);
  });
  
  const resolvablePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.resolve = resolve;
    self.reject = reject;
  });

  // This gives you the promise functionality.
  const proxyPromise = Promise.all([timerPromise, resolvablePromise]);
  
  proxyPromise.resolve = self.resolve;
  proxyPromise.reject = self.reject;
  
  return proxyPromise;
}

console.log('start', new Date());
const p = new DelayedPromise(1000);
p.then(function() { console.log('resolved', new Date()); });
p.resolve();
```

And here is a possibility for how to use it:

```
class ExampleComponentUsingLoader extends Component {

  checkForallFalseValues = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(val){ 
      return obj[val] === false 
    })
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.delayedPromise = new DelayedPromise(1000)

    this.state = { loading: true }
    this.delayedPromise.then(() => this.setState({ loading: false }))
  }

  render(){
    const { isLoading } = this.props
    if (checkForAllFalseValues(isLoading)) {
      this.delayedPromise.resolve();
    }
    return(
        { this.state.loading && <LoadingIndicator /> }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for considering this issue! I think you've given me a few things to think about. One issue I think this solution has is that it will likely work on the first render but not for subsequent renders. So if the `ExampleComponentUsingLoader` receives an update to its `isLoading` props, we would expect the loader to display again with a 1000ms delay but the timer won't trigger because it's only set for the initial render.

Comment: In that case I would probably either go with the more complex example and create a new `DelayedPromise` or go with the first one and pull the timeout piece out into a function that will start the timeout again.